# Using twitter API how do I get the date to display?

Tags: twitter

I feel like I'm the only one who doesn't know. This is my array:

```
foreach($tweets as $idx => $tweet) {
            $variables[] = array(
                'tweet' => (string) $tweet->text,
                                    'tweet-time' => created_at 
            );
```

How do I get the current date (created_at) to display here in the array?

Comment: I didn't fully understand what you mean showing the current date in array. Can you please explain more of your question?

Comment: Sorry I figured it out - I needed 'date' => (string) $tweet->created_at to display the date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed 'date' => (string) $tweet->created_at to display the date